# Mapping single-level map to nested map with Dozer

Tags: java, hashmap, nested, dozer

I'm having trouble mapping a simple HashMap onto a nested Hashmap.
My simple source map has a sourceMapKey and a sourceMapValue. This source map is supposed to be mapped to a target map. The target map is supposed to end up with a targetSubMap containing the mapped sourceMapKey and sourceMapValue like this:

```
 {targetSubMap={targetMapkey=sourceMapValue}}
```

My code looks like this:

```
HashMap<Object, Object> sourceMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();  
sourceMap.put("sourceMapKey", "sourceMapValue");
List<String> myMappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
myMappingFiles.add("file:\\C:\\mapping.xml");
DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.setMappingFiles(myMappingFiles);
HashMap<Object, Object> targetMap = mapper.map(sourceMap, HashMap.class, "MainMap");
```

My mapping.xml looks like this:

```
 <mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">  

 <mapping map-id="MainMap">
  <class-a is-accessible="true">java.util.HashMap</class-a>
  <class-b is-accessible="true">java.util.HashMap</class-b>
  <field map-id="SubMap">
   <a>this</a>
   <b key="targetSubMap">this</b>
   <a-hint>java.util.HashMap</a-hint>
   <b-hint>java.util.HashMap</b-hint>
  </field>
 </mapping>  

 <mapping map-id="SubMap">
 <class-a>java.util.HashMap</class-a>
 <class-b>java.util.HashMap</class-b>
 <field>
   <a key="sourceMapKey">this</a>
   <b key="targetMapKey">this</b>
   <a-hint>java.util.HashMap</a-hint>
   <b-hint>java.util.HashMap</b-hint>
 </field>
 </mapping>
</mappings>
```

The result I get in the target map is:

```
{targetSubMap=null}
```

What am I doing wrong?